# Weird intermittent Internet symptom

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I live in Thailand and An antenna receives  Wi-Fi signal from a shop 3 kilometers away; the signal passes through a D-Link router and is rebroadcast throughout my home. Usually it works OK. But sometimes I suddenly start getting errors like `(113) No route to host` or `(110) Connection timed out.`

When the problem occurs, the website(s) will be inaccessible for a few minutes and then be OK. This may happen repeatedly throughout the day. Or I can go several days with no problem and, then (as happened today) the problem starts recurring. Only some websites are affected, but they include some I use a lot: Wikipedia, boards.straightdope.com.

The problem affects both Chrome and Firefox, but never occurs with Tor. Lately I keep a Tor browser up and use it whenever a page becomes inaccessible. I never see the symptoms with Tor (though it has other inconveniences).

My provider thinks the problem may be some “rogue router” that collides with our signal. But that wouldn't explain why Tor works OK, right? BTW, provider gets his Internet from multiple ISP's to increase the up-time his customers get. Could that be related?

Several months ago, my D-Link was hijacked (there was a news story) but the symptoms were unrelated and my provider (the small shop 3 km away) fixed it. Related?

Thailand censors the Internet. I've conjectured that the problem occurs when the ISP's censoring mechanism gets overloaded. Plausible? But I don’t see symptoms similar to mine posted on Thailand message boards.

Someone suggested I change DNS settings. The problem is too intermittent to be completely sure whether that changed the symptoms slightly, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Just an observation--I'm surprised you get any signal at all.  Wifi range is up to a few hundred feet in ideal conditions.  At 3 km, I'm amazed you ever have a usable signal.

Comment: He probably means [WISP](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_internet_service_provider) not Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

You say that TOR works, but other connections don’t, correct? That to me points to a DNS issue. Meaning when you get a `No route to host` that means your machine has no idea how to get to a site. This is typically because of either a loss in your Internet connectivity overall, but if you still have TOR connected it is VPN’ed into something. And that something that still has active DNS.  So to me it seems it’s all a DNS issue.

And the way I believe this is playing out is when you get your connection from your ISP it is via DHCP which provides DNS servers from your ISP. Chances are those DNS servers are the ones going down.  And the way to fix the issue is to manually set your own DNS values which is what I like to do.  I like to use OpenDNS—for example—so I set the DNS entries on my machine to be `208.67.220.222` and `208.67.220.220` which are the OpenDNS servers.

As for why the DNS servers are going down or how it might related to larger government censorship? I would not even know how to begin to assess that. But if you ask me personally, I believe that any government or entity that is attempting to “short circuit” the way the Internet should works usually does a “half baked” job of doing so. Meaning it is conceivable that your ISP is using some official Thailand DNS services that just craps out all the time. And that is the source of your issue. And if you can VPN past that with TOR or perhaps explicitly setting DNS entries, then that speaks volumes to how futile such an effort like that is.  Which is a whole other discussion that’s not worthing discussing.

Comment: I have tried changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.  It seemed to get better but failed the next day as before.  I wasn't sure whether DNS made a difference, or the problem's intermittency made the result inconclusive.  I'll try your DNS suggestion.  But the problem occurs after I've already accessed a domain successfully; with name cache, could it still be DNS that causes trouble?

Comment: As for whether my input is "Wifi", I've wondered that myself, but my provider insists it is.  Ignorance may be a big problem.  :-(  I will point out that I use a special directional antenna atop roof, and it has to be meticulously aimed to get good signal. ... I'm new here.  It seems there is a severe restriction on message length.  :-(